# Microsoft Outlook add-in change request

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have developed an outlook add-in and posted on Microsoft appstore.
But I got validation error report with change request as below:

4.12.1 Add in commands do not appear in the Outlook 2016 Desktop Client or in the Outlook 2016 Client on Mac -  there appears to be an issue in the version overrides element in your manifest file

This is the manifest:

```
<OfficeApp
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
          xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
          xsi:type="MailApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>a0fc93fd-3de0-4a0a-b856-8f5e15c8f91d</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>WritingAssistant</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="WritingAssistant for Outlook" />
  <Description DefaultValue="The fastest, easiest way to improve your grammar and writing."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/logo-64.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/logo-80.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.writing-assistant.com/contact.htm" />
  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain1</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.5" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/MessageRead.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="ReadOrEdit" />
  </Rule>

  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
          <FunctionFile resid="Contoso.FunctionFile.Url" />

          <!-- Message Read -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
            <CustomTab id="customTabLabel">

              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon64" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
              <Group id="Contoso.Tab1.Group5">
                <Label resid="Contoso.Tab1.GroupLabel2" />
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.TranslateWord">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.TranslateWord.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Contoso.TranslateWord.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Contoso.TranslateWord.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.TranslateWord.Icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.TranslateWord.Icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="Contoso.TranslateWord.Icon64" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.TranslateWord.Icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.TranslateWord.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.DS">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.DS.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Contoso.DS.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Contoso.DS.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.DS.Icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.DS.Icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="Contoso.DS.Icon64" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.DS.Icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.DS.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>

              </Group>
              <Group id="Contoso.Tab1.Group2">
                <Label resid="Contoso.Tab1.GroupLabel2" />
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.MyDictionary">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.MyDictionary.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Contoso.MyDictionary.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Contoso.MyDictionary.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.MyDictionary.Icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.MyDictionary.Icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="Contoso.MyDictionary.Icon64" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.MyDictionary.Icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.MyDictionary.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.MyStatistics">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.MyStatistics.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Contoso.MyStatistics.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Contoso.MyStatistics.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.MyStatistics.Icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.MyStatistics.Icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="Contoso.MyStatistics.Icon64" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.MyStatistics.Icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.MyStatistics.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.Download">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.Download.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Contoso.Download.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Contoso.Download.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.Download.Icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.Download.Icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="Contoso.Download.Icon64" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.Download.Icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>report</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>

              <Group id="Contoso.Tab1.Group4">
                <Label resid="Contoso.Tab1.GroupLabel4" />
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.setting">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.setting.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Contoso.setting.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Contoso.setting.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.setting.Icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.setting.Icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="Contoso.setting.Icon64" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.setting.Icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane5.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.FAQ">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.FAQ.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Contoso.FAQ.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Contoso.FAQ.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.FAQ.Icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.FAQ.Icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="Contoso.FAQ.Icon64" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.FAQ.Icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>faq</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>

                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.Tour">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.Tour.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Contoso.Tour.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Contoso.Tour.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.Tour.Icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.Tour.Icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="Contoso.Tour.Icon64" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.Tour.Icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>Tour</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>

                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.logout">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.logout.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Contoso.logout.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Contoso.logout.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.logout.Icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.logout.Icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="Contoso.logout.Icon64" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.logout.Icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.logout.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
              <Group id="Contoso.Tab1.Group3">
                <Label resid="Contoso.Tab1.GroupLabel3" />
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.Check">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.Check.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Contoso.Check.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Contoso.Check.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.Check.Icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.Check.Icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="Contoso.Check.Icon64" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.Check.Icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane3.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>

                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.Clear">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.Clear.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Contoso.Clear.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Contoso.Clear.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.Clear.Icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.Clear.Icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="Contoso.Clear.Icon64" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.Clear.Icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane4.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.Error">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.ErrorList.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Contoso.ErrorList.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Contoso.ErrorList.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.ErrList.Icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.ErrList.Icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="Contoso.ErrList.Icon64" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.ErrList.Icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <!--Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane -->
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.ErrorList.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
              <Label resid="customTabLabel.TabLabel" />
            </CustomTab>

          </ExtensionPoint>
          <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>

        <bt:Image id="Contoso.setting.Icon16" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.setting.Icon32" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.setting.Icon64" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-64.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.setting.Icon80" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-80.png" />

        <bt:Image id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon16" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/logo-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon32" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/logo-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon64" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/logo-64.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon80" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/logo-80.png" />

        <bt:Image id="Contoso.Check.Icon16" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/check-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.Check.Icon32" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/check-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.Check.Icon64" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/check-64.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.Check.Icon80" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/check-80.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.MyDictionary.Icon16" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/my-dictionary-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.MyDictionary.Icon32" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/my-dictionary-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.MyDictionary.Icon64" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/my-dictionary-64.png" />
                  <bt:Image id="Contoso.Download.Icon80" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/download-80.png" />
       <bt:Image id="Contoso.TranslateWord.Icon16" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/translate-word-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.TranslateWord.Icon32" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/translate-word-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.TranslateWord.Icon64" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/translate-word-64.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.TranslateWord.Icon80" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/translate-word-80.png" />

        <bt:Image id="Contoso.WordDefinition.Icon16" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/wd-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.WordDefinition.Icon32" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/wd-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.WordDefinition.Icon64" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/wd-64.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.WordDefinition.Icon80" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/wd-80.png" />

        <bt:Image id="Contoso.Synonyms.Icon16" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/synonyms-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.Synonyms.Icon32" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/synonyms-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.Synonyms.Icon64" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/synonyms-64.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.Synonyms.Icon80" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/synonyms-80.png" />

        <bt:Image id="Contoso.Clear.Icon16" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/clear-icon-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.Clear.Icon32" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/clear-icon-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.Clear.Icon64" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/clear-icon-64.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.Clear.Icon80" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/clear-icon-80.png" />

        <bt:Image id="Contoso.logout.Icon16" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/logout-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.logout.Icon32" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/logout-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.logout.Icon64" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/logout-64.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.logout.Icon80" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/logout-80.png" />

        <bt:Image id="Contoso.ErrList.Icon16" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/list-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.ErrList.Icon32" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/list-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.ErrList.Icon64" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/list-64.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.ErrList.Icon80" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/list-80.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.FunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Functions/FunctionFile.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.Taskpane3.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/UI/Accordion.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/UI/Login.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.Taskpane4.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/UI/Clear.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.TranslateWord.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/UI/Translate.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.WordDefinition.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/UI/GetWordDefinition.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.Synonyms.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/UI/Synonym.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.MyDictionary.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/UI/GetMyDictionary.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.MyStatistics.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/UI/Statistics.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.Download.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/UI/Download.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.DS.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/UI/DefinitionandSynonyms.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.FAQ.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/UI/Login.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.Tour.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/UI/Login.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.ErrorList.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/UI/ErrorList.html"/>

        <bt:Url id="Contoso.Taskpane5.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/UI/Setting.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.logout.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/UI/Logout.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue=" "/>
        <bt:String id="customTabLabel"  DefaultValue="My Add-in Tab"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="WritingAssistant"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Get all properties"/>
        <bt:String id="customTabLabel.TabLabel" DefaultValue="WritingAssistant" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Check.Label" DefaultValue="Check" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.TranslateWord.Label" DefaultValue="Translate" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.WordDefinition.Label" DefaultValue="Word Definition" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Synonyms.Label" DefaultValue="Synonyms" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.MyDictionary.Label" DefaultValue="My Dictionary" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.MyStatistics.Label" DefaultValue="Statistics" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Download.Label" DefaultValue="Download Report" />

        <bt:String id="Contoso.DS.Label" DefaultValue="Word Definition" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.FAQ.Label" DefaultValue="FAQs" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Tour.Label" DefaultValue="Tour" />

        <bt:String id="Contoso.Tab1.GroupLabel2" DefaultValue=" " />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label2" DefaultValue="Check" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.TranslateWord.Label2" DefaultValue="Translate" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.WordDefinition.Label2" DefaultValue="Word Definition" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Synonyms.Label2" DefaultValue="Synonyms" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.MyDictionary.Label2" DefaultValue="Open My Dictionary" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.MyStatistics.Label2" DefaultValue="Statistics" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Download.Label2" DefaultValue="Download Report" />
         <bt:String id="Contoso.DS.Label2" DefaultValue="DS" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.FAQ.Label2" DefaultValue="Open FAQ" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Tour.Label2" DefaultValue="Tour" />

        <bt:String id="Contoso.Clear.Label" DefaultValue="Clear Highlights" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Tab1.GroupLabel3" DefaultValue=" " />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.logout.Label" DefaultValue="Logout" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.setting.Label" DefaultValue="Settings" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Tab1.logout" DefaultValue=" " />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Tab1.GroupLabel4" DefaultValue=" " />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.ErrorList.Label" DefaultValue="Error List" />

      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Open WritingAssistant for a comprehensive analysis of your writing."/>
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Check.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Check your writing for grammatical errors." />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.TranslateWord.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Translating English to German? Or Hindi to Urdu? The Translate tool has got it covered. Simply enter a word, select a language of your choice, and get started. " />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.WordDefinition.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Having trouble with a certain word? Type it in the dictionary search bar for the exact meaning and a short description." />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Synonyms.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Running out of words? Allow us to suggest more options to express the same idea in different words." />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.MyDictionary.Tooltip" DefaultValue="A modifiable collection of your most frequently used words" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.MyStatistics.Tooltip" DefaultValue="View a summary of your performance in each category: Mechanics, Grammar, Content Quality, and Vocabulary." />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Download.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to download Report" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.DS.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Running out of words? Allow us to suggest more options to express the same idea in different words." />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.FAQ.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Have questions about WritingAssistant? We are happy to help." />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Tour.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Buckle up for a tour of WritingAssistant." />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Clear.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Clear the current errors from your text and the list." />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.logout.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Log out of WritingAssistant and return to the home page." />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.setting.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Customise error subcategories for an experience tailored to your needs." />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.ErrorList.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to get Error list " />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>

  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

I don't understand what is needed to change here, as I 'm a beginner

Comment: Please provide entire manifest, not the part of it. Manifest starts at `OfficeApp` tag.

Comment: yeah, I updated

Comment: You could refer to the below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/manifests

You could change your manifest according to this link.

Answer (score 1):

The manifest provided has several mistakes, probably just inattention to copy&paste inside `Resources` section. The following `Images` were missing ...

```
<bt:Image id="Contoso.Tour.Icon16" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-16.png" />
<bt:Image id="Contoso.Tour.Icon32" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-32.png" />
<bt:Image id="Contoso.Tour.Icon64" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-64.png" />
<bt:Image id="Contoso.Tour.Icon80" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-80.png" />

<bt:Image id="Contoso.FAQ.Icon16" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-16.png" />
<bt:Image id="Contoso.FAQ.Icon32" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-32.png" />
<bt:Image id="Contoso.FAQ.Icon64" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-64.png" />
<bt:Image id="Contoso.FAQ.Icon80" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-80.png" />

<bt:Image id="Contoso.DS.Icon16" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-16.png" />
<bt:Image id="Contoso.DS.Icon32" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-32.png" />
<bt:Image id="Contoso.DS.Icon64" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-64.png" />
<bt:Image id="Contoso.DS.Icon80" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-80.png" />

<bt:Image id="Contoso.MyStatistics.Icon16" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-16.png" />
<bt:Image id="Contoso.MyStatistics.Icon32" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-32.png" />
<bt:Image id="Contoso.MyStatistics.Icon64" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-64.png" />
<bt:Image id="Contoso.MyStatistics.Icon80" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/setting-80.png" />

<bt:Image id="Contoso.MyDictionary.Icon80" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/my-dictionary-80.png" />

<bt:Image id="Contoso.Download.Icon16" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/download-16.png" />
<bt:Image id="Contoso.Download.Icon32" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/download-32.png" />
<bt:Image id="Contoso.Download.Icon64" DefaultValue="https://outlookplugin.writing-assistant.com/Images/download-64.png" />
```

As long as I added those missing entries the add-in was loaded (obviosly you would need to change the icons for those missing `IDs`) ...

[image]

Comment: that I excluded while pasting here, because I couldn't paste the entire content as it is greater than 30000 number

Comment: It looks like Slava can load your manifest fine in destkop outlook after adding in the entries? (given his screenshot) If yours is not, what's the difference between the stuff he added, and what's in your manifest? Is it possible one of your resources isn't loading?